# Como adicionar +10 segundos inteiros ao date em um loop no PHP

Tags: php, loop, data

Preciso que o `loop` seja executado **10** vezes, e que a cada `loop` a variável `$tempo` que tem a *data*, *hora*, *minuto* e *segundos* receba **+10** segundos, mas que no resultado final não seja exibido em segundos fragmentados, ex 08, 15, 59, desejo apenas inteiros, ou mais especificamente `00`, `10`, `20`, `30`, `40`, `50`.

O resultado da variável `$tempo` no `loop` deveria ser algo como:

```
2001_12_15_001510
2001_12_15_001520
2001_12_15_001530
2001_12_15_001540
2001_12_15_001550
2001_12_15_001600
2001_12_15_001610
2001_12_15_001620
2001_12_15_001630
2001_12_15_001640
```

Só consegui obter os segundos em números inteiros sem o loop com

```
if(in_array($segundos, range("00", "09"))){
    $segundos = "00";
}
```

Comment: Em qual sistema operacional? Uma resposta curta depende do `strptime()` pra converter a data no formato `2001-12-15 00:15:19`, mas essa função não é implementada no Windows.

Comment: Estou rodando o php no windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi exatamente o que você está tentando fazer.
Mas esse código vai listar exatamente o que você quer.
Me deixe saber se não é o que você precisa.
Por favor publique algum trecho do seu código para eu saber melhor o que você precisa.

```
$time = strtotime(str_replace('_', '', '2001_12_15_001510'));
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo date('Y_m_d_His', $time).' - '.$time.'<br>';
    $time += 10;
}
```

A saída fica assim

```
2001_12_15_001510 - 1008371710
2001_12_15_001520 - 1008371720
2001_12_15_001530 - 1008371730
2001_12_15_001540 - 1008371740
2001_12_15_001550 - 1008371750
2001_12_15_001600 - 1008371760
2001_12_15_001610 - 1008371770
2001_12_15_001620 - 1008371780
2001_12_15_001630 - 1008371790
2001_12_15_001640 - 1008371800
```

Como você pode ver, você tem apenas os segundos ou a data com o formato que você pediu.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela rapidez, pude implementar e testar.

Answer (score 1):

Os números saem quebrados porque a entrada tem um valor que não é múltiplo de dez. Pra corrigir isso, você precisa avançar para o tempo mais próximo cujo segundos é múltiplo de 10.

Fazemos isso com o operador *mod* (em PHP, `%`), ele pega o resto de uma divisão. Suponha que os segundos sejam 32, precisamos chegar em 40 pra começar ir adicionando de 10 em 10. Você divide o 32 por 10, e pega o resto da divisão, que é 2. A diferença entre 10 e 2 (10 - 2 = 8) é o que precisamos adicionar pra chegar no 40 (32 + 8 = 40). A expressão completa é `32 + (10 - (32 % 10)) = 40`

Veja a implementação:

```
// Define a zona antes de mexer com DateTime
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

// A data inicial tem que estar nesse formato (ISO 8601)
$inicial = '2012-07-08 11:14:58';

$tempo = new DateTime($inicial);

// Encontra o horário mais próximo com os segundos múltiplo de 10
$addSegundos = 10 - ($tempo->format('s') % 10);
$tempo->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$addSegundos.'S'));

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    if ($i != 0)
        // Adiciona 10 segundos ao $tempo
        $tempo->add(new DateInterval('PT10S'));

    echo $tempo->format("Y_m_d_His\n");
}
```

Comment: Bem explicado, mas preferi a outra por ser mais simples de implementar.

Comment: Tranquilo, entendi que vc precisava lidar com entradas onde os segundos estão quebrados. Se os segundos já forem múltiplos de 10, a outra resposta é mais apropriada.